# Checking a Device Driver in Windows Server 2003 with SNMP

Tags: windows, snmp

I'm interested in checking the status of a video card on a remote machine running Windows Server 2003 and was wondering if this was possible to do via SNMP?

In particular, I was wondering if the SNMP services expose whether or not a particular device driver is loaded?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to write an extension so information about this driver can be published via SNMP.

You can find technical details here,
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750391.aspx